# An inequality for a sum of sine functions

Tags: inequality, trigonometric-series

I want to show for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the following inequality holds.
$$
\left|\sin x\right|+\left|\sin (x+1)\right|+\left|\sin (x+2)\right|>8/5.
$$
This trigonometric inequality has been verified by Mathematica using the Plot commend. However, using the sum formula for the sine function seems doesn't work, and I cannot give a rigorous proof of it. Any suggestion, idea, or comment is welcome, thanks!

Comment: The left-hand side seems to have an upper bound $14/5$.

Comment: Are you sure there's not a typo in the LHS ?

Comment: typo: $\left|\sin (x+1)\right| \rightarrow \left|\sin (x+2)\right|$

Comment: HINT: try to show that the minimum value is reached when $x+1=0$ using what you knows about the sine function.

Comment: Yes, in fact the minimum value is $2\sin 1=1.683...>8/5$.

Comment: the general case for searching the minimum for $$f(x,n):=\left|\sin x\right|+\left|\sin (x+1)\right|+\left|\sin (x+2)\right|+...+\left|\sin (x+n)\right|$$ is not as easy as I thought in first place. It seems that the solution doesnt have a closed form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $f:x\mapsto \left|\sin x\right|+\left|\sin (x+1)\right|+\left|\sin (x+2)\right|$ is $\pi$-periodic, it suffices to prove the inequality for $x\in [0,\pi]$.

Also note that $$\begin{cases} f(x)  = \sin(x)+\sin(x+1)+\sin(x+2) & \text{if } x\in [0,\pi-2]  \\
f(x)= \sin(x)+\sin(x+1)-\sin(x+2) & \text{if } x\in [\pi-2,\pi-1] \\
f(x) = \sin(x)-\sin(x+1)-\sin(x+2) & \text{if } x\in [\pi-1,\pi] \end{cases}$$

Note that each of the subfunction is concave on each of the relevant interval. For example, if you let $f_2(x)=\sin(x)+\sin(x+1)-\sin(x+2)$, $$f_2''(x)=-f_2(x)\leq 0 \quad \text{when } x\in [\pi-2,\pi-1]$$
The argument is similar for the other functions.
Therefore, each subfunction reaches its minimum at the boundary of its domain, hence $f$ reaches a minimum which is $$\min(f(0),f(\pi-2),f(\pi-1)) $$

Note that $$f(0)=f(\pi-2)= \sin(1)+\sin(2)\sim1.75$$ and $$f(\pi-1)=2\sin (1)\sim 1.68$$

The minimum is therefore $2\sin( 1)\sim 1.68 > \frac 85$

Comment: I'm wondering if the inequality can be generalized to the function $\left|\sin x\right|+\left|\sin (x+1)\right|+\left|\sin (x+2)\right|+...+\left|\sin (x+n)\right|$, where $n$ is any natural number. Also, can we also find the upper and bounds which depend on $n$?

Comment: The proof above adapts readily for the minimum. Just note that if $n\geq 4$, $\sin(x+n)\leq 0$ for all $x\in [0,\pi]$.

Comment: I'm also thinking about the generalization to the elliptic sine function $sn(x,k)$ with the property that $sn(x,k)\to\sin x$ as $k\to0$. This seems possible.

Comment: wtf, this edit is nonsense

Comment: What is the matter?

Comment: @LCH someone had edited the answer and made it completely wrong (see http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/2183125/4 )

Comment: To find the maximum value, I find it needs to solve the equations like $\cos (x)+\cos (x+1)-\cos (x+2)=0$. Seems this can only be solve numerically?

Comment: @LCH No, you can bruteforce each sum into a single sine/cosine. Wolfram Mathematica tells me for example that $$\sin(x) - \sin(x+1) - \sin(x+2) = \sqrt{3-2 \cos (2)} \sin \left(x+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin (1)+\sin (2)}{-1+\cos (1)+\cos (2)}\right)\right)$$

Comment: I see. In addition to the generalization to the elliptic sine function and to the function $\left|\sin x\right|+\left|\sin (x+1)\right|+\left|\sin (x+2)\right|+...+\left|\sin (x+n)\right|$, do you have any other more nontrivial generalization?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55224/discussion-between-lch-and-legranddodom).